# Adding elements to another XML-file

Tags: xml, xsd

Here's XML-1:

```xml
<bookstore>
  <book category="children">
    <title>Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  </book>
  <book category="web">
    <title>Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

How do I create XML-2 based on XML-1 by adding two elements `<year>` and `<price>`?
It does not copy XML-1, but by referring or including it. This separation is necessary to store XML-1 and XML-2 separately and not to duplicate information from XML-1 in XML-2.

To eventually be able to create XML-3:

```xml
<bookstore>
  <book category="children">
    <title>Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web">
    <title>Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

**How should the XML-2 schema look like?**
I can not understand how to use the references and inclusions. Do I need to use them in this case at all or do I need something other?

Answer (score 1):

You can use xsd extension functionality :
https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-schema-tutorial/xsd-extending-types

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="bookstore">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="book" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="title"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="author"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="category" use="optional"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

You need to create an extended book :

```
<xs:complexType name="ExtendedBook">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="book">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element type="xs:short" name="year"/>
               <xs:element type="xs:float" name="price"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```